# Cómo desinstalar la versión más reciente de R sin borrar las anteriores en ubuntu

Tags: r, ubuntu, rstudio

Estoy teniendo problemas con la instalación de algunos paquetes en Rstudio con la versión 4.2.1. En las carpetas del ordenador, veo que esos paquetes están instalados en la versión 4.1. No encuentro la manera de desisntalar una versión específica de R.

PD: los paquetes problemáticos son 'car' y 'FSA'.

Answer (score 0):

Con el comando `remove.packages("c(car, FSA)")` deberías de poder borrar estos dos paquetes y después volver a instalar si quisieras.